# Чем отличается взятие остатка по модулю от просто взятия остатка?

Tags: алгоритм, математика, операторы

Что означает "по модулю"? Почему не назвали просто операция взятия остатка? В языке программирования С операция `%` - это взятие остатка по модулю или просто взятие остатка?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC - поиск, как всегда, выручает.

Comment: Поиск-то выручает. Просто я хочу почему именно "по модулю"?

Comment: @Flyte: «модулем» называется делитель, «остаток по модулю 7» = «остаток при _делении_ на 7».

Comment: > это взятие остатка по модулю или просто взятие остатка?

Правильно "взятие остатка" и "деление по модулю" (а не взятие остатка по модулю). Это одна и та же операция. Как называть - дело вкуса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ничем не отличается, просто разные люди называют одно и то же по-разному.

Comment: Вы не правы ...

Comment: @Mirdin: Остаток по модулю и модуль числа лишь случайно называются похожим словом. Автор вопроса же явно имеет в виду именно остаток при делении.

Comment: насколько я знаю не случайно, мне попадались статьи где операциями "по модулю" называли именно эйлерову арифметику, о чем я и написал в ответе ниже.

Answer (score 0):

Модуль в математике - это абсолютная величина числа, независимая от его знака.

В целочисленной арифметике деление отрицательных чисел (и соответственно взятие остатка) будет несколько отличатся от ожидаемого

```
32 / 10 = 3
32 % 10 = 2

-32 / 10 = -4
-32 / 10 = 8
```

ЕМНИП, "взятием остатка по модулю" называют такую операцию при которой сохраняется знак, но само взятие остатка применяется к модулю числа таким образом:

```
-32 / 10 = -3
-32 % 10 = -2
```

Comment: Вы не в теме. В математике «по модулю» — вещь, отличная от абсолютной величины. Просто совпали слова.

Comment: А что означает «ЕМНИМ»? Это что-то вроде IMHO?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, Опечатка - ЕМНИП - Если Мне Не Изменяет Память